# Can we undo "close" votes?

Tags: discussion

I voted to close a "duplicate" [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/finding-the-offset-for-ext4-partition).

After posting a answer, and getting a comment from the OP, I realised that it was not a duplicate.... Now I cannot remove my close-vote... is there a way?

Answer (score 3):

No, there's currently no way to do so. There was a [feature request for it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes), but it got declined; for now hopefully others will see the OP's comment and not also vote to close, and after two days your vote will disappear